# Number of components in the pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a method declaration like this:

```
void createProgram(int32_t dev, int32_t* pixelId, int32_t* vertexId)
```

How can I discover the number of elements in the pixelId and vertexId arrays?

For example, I tried to find out the contained number of elements with:

```
sizeof(pixelId)/sizeof(int32_t)
```

but this isn't the solution, sizeof(pixelId) returns the size of the pointer.

Is there another solution?

Thanks

Comment: Well, by passing it. But that's probably not your intended question, so I'd recommend clarifying it.

Comment: Unless you pass it along as an argument, or use e.g. `std::vector`, you can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your title, I *think* you want to find out how many elements are being passed in the `pixelId` and `vertexId` parameters. In short, you can't - all a pointer does is say that at that point in memory there are `int32_t`'s, not how many. You either have to:

1. Specify the size of the array(s) in an extra parameter
2. Use a collection encapsulation class like `std::vector` to pass them
3. Close the array with a 'magic' number, that cannot normally occur in the array, to indicate its end. Strings for example are usually zero-terminated `char*`'s, which is valid since a zero-byte is not a valid ASCII or Unicode character.

Without using one of these 3 methods a pointer is just a memory address and an indication of the datatype it's pointing to, not how many elements, if any at all, are there.

You tried:

```
sizeof(pixelId)/sizeof(int32_t)
```

Since `pixelId` is a `int32_t*`, it's a memory pointer, which is either 4 or 8 bytes based on whether you're on a 32- or 64-bit OS. `sizeof(int32_t)` is 4 bytes by definition, so this calculation will either return `2` or `1`, but not an answer related to *what is being pointed to by the pointer*.